# Error in code block

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am getting two errors in code block which I am not able to remove. I think they are linking errors:

```
ld   can't find -lc  
ld   can't find -lm
```

Comment: May we see the code you're getting an error at?

Comment: I doubt that seeing the code would help.  It looks like a Code::Blocks configuration error.  Can you try building on the command line?

Comment: @user722233, are you using Code::Blocks or are you referring to the block of code?

Comment: error in code block software ,no error in program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have set correctly LD_LIBRARY_PATH for searching library path. The linker is looking for static library files libc.a and libm.a. They are standard c library and math library.

Comment: how to check and set the path for liberary

Comment: You may read `1.11.13  Including libraries` in [CodeBlocks Manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html)